# Trying to use MSAL - why is EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi not available?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

I have been scouring sites trying to find the solution, but clearly I am doing something simple because this appears to be unique.

I am following some code  -

```
        public static void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app, string redirectUri)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            // Get an TokenAcquirerFactory specialized for OWIN
            OwinTokenAcquirerFactory owinTokenAcquirerFactory = TokenAcquirerFactory.GetDefaultInstance<OwinTokenAcquirerFactory>();

            // Configure the web app.
            app.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(owinTokenAcquirerFactory);

            // Add the services you need.
            owinTokenAcquirerFactory.Services
                 .Configure<ConfidentialClientApplicationOptions>(
                    options => {
                        options.RedirectUri = redirectUri;
                        options.ClientSecret = clientSecret;
                    })
                 .AddMicrosoftGraph()
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

            owinTokenAcquirerFactory.Build();
        }
```

I should be able to add .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi() to the owinTokenFactory.Services, but it does not show up.

These are my usings...

```
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.Graph;
    using Microsoft.Identity.Abstractions;
    using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
    using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
    using Microsoft.Identity.Web.OWIN;
    using Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenCacheProviders.InMemory;
    using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
    using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
    using Owin;
    using System.Net.Http.Headers;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

What am I missing?

:(

thx